# Set monospace font for all elements that use monospace fonts in CSS

Tags: html, css

In my website I want to use Noto Sans for all the text except for the places where it should be monospace, like `<code>`, `<pre>`, etc., where I want to use Noto Sans Mono.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to look at the list of all the tags which use monospace font?

I would prefer to only use HTML and CSS.

Comment: There is not, you will have to globally target all elements that display in monospace. Lucky for you, thats a CSS only solution.

Comment: As far as I know there are only 5 tags that on default have monospace font, so it won't be so hard to create a valid selector

Comment: @AdrianKokot - Not even that. There's 8 in total, but 4 of them are obsolete.

Comment: @AdrianKokot Which ones?

Comment: Excluding the deprecated ones: [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code), [`kbd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd), [`samp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/samp). In some browsers also: [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) and [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var)

Comment: @AdrianKokot - Which browsers make `var` monospaced by default?

Comment: Well, I assumed it was possible due to the mdn explanation, but if you're sure that's always italic than my bad, `var` should not be in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Using the body selector in the CSS code above, we first made "Noto Sans" the default font for the entire page's body. Then, to target every element that needs a monospace font, we utilise the attribute selector [code], pre, tt, kbd, samp.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
}

code, pre, tt, kbd, samp {
  font-family: "Noto Sans Mono", monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>regular text</p>
<code>monospace text</code>
<pre>monospace text within a pre element</pre>
```

Comment: Why do you target the attribute selector `[code]` rather than simply the `code` element?

Comment: The CSS selector code would only target the <code> element, while [code] would target both the <code> element and the <span> element because it has a code attribute.

Comment: I don't think [`<span>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) has a `code` attribute, does it? It looks like it only has the [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) according to the spec.

Comment: You're absolutely correct; I apologize for the oversight, and I appreciate you bringing it to my attention. Thank you for catching that error, and I'll ensure it corrected.